# Regex.Unescape() não funciona

Tags: c#, regex

Meu projeto possui uma classe com a propriedade do tipo *string* que recebe o XML de uma Nota Fiscal assinada pelo SEFAZ. O sistema deve enviar a propriedade como parâmetro para um `WebService` que apenas retorna um erro.

Depurando notei que a propriedade `NotaFiscalXML` fica com o resultado da consulta do XML sem escape. Quando o sistema concatena a propriedade com o 'envelope' da requisição os escapes são adicionados. Segundo o suporte do desenvolvedor do *WS*, é necessário remover os escapes para que não haja erros na requisição. Tendo essa resposta decidi usar a função `Regex.Unescape()` mas mesmo assim propriedade continua contendo *Char Escape* antes das aspas. O codigo a seguir é um pequeno exemplo de como estou desenvolvendo:

```
private string _notaFiscalXML {get; set;}
public string NotaFiscalXML {get => _notaFiscalXML; set => _notaFiscalXML = value;}

string EstruturaEnvelope ="";
string Envelope = "";

NotaFiscalXML = "<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe"><infNFe id="NFe123" versao="4.00"> conteudo NF </NFe></infNFe>";

Estrutura += "<x:Envelope ";
Estrutura += "    xmlns:x='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'";
Estrutura += "    xmlns:tem='http://tempuri.org/'> ";
Estrutura += "    <x:Header/>";
Estrutura += "    <x:Body> ";
Estrutura += "      <tem:NotaFiscalIntegrar>";
Estrutura += "        <tem:xml> ";
Estrutura += $"         {NotaFiscalXML.Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;")} ";
Estrutura += "        </tem:xml> ";
Estrutura += "      </tem:NotaFiscalIntegrar> ";
Estrutura += "    </x:Body> ";
Estrutura += "</x:Envelope> ";       
Envelope = Regex.Unescape(Estrutura.Replace("'", "\""));
```

Como resultado eu tenho o seguinte envelope:

```
<x:Envelope xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
    xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">
    <x:Header/>
    <x:Body>
        <tem:NotaFiscalIntegrar>
            <tem:xml>          &lt;NFe xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\"&gt;&lt;infNFe id=\"NFe123\" versao=\"4.00\"&gt; conteudo NF &lt;/NFe&gt;&lt;/infNFe&gt;         </tem:xml>
        </tem:NotaFiscalIntegrar>
    </x:Body>
</x:Envelope>
```

Comment: Por que você está concatenando essa string para gerar o seu xml?

Comment: Segundo o suporte do WebService se faz necessário concatenar a XML com a estrutura do envelope para enviar a requisição...

Comment: Mas por que você não importa o contrato e gera os objetos da forma adequada para tirar proveito das classes de serialização do próprio .net?